# What’s a pithy saying expressing that those more ready to find fault in others do so because they are more inclined to a self-serving viewpoint?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, aphorism-requests

I am looking for a colorful folk saying or poetic aphorism which succinctly expresses the idea that when someone is unhesitantly ready to let you know how bad and in the wrong you are about something, it on the surface can create a pretext where you are on trial and given that they are accusing you of something, it can shift the balance or attention from the possibility that they could have done something wrong, to that you may have done something wrong, or not, but that by default, you seem to be the one who is implicitly the bad one.

The idea is that people who have way less restraint in condemning and criticizing other people may asymmetrically do so because they are not preoccupied with fairness; they are so concerned with the blatant moral badness of other people and unquestionably assuming their own rightness that even though they are making more of the accusations, in the background there is the possibility that their behavior is the more immoral, less constructive, less harmonious, less prosocial one.

It’s sort of like the liar’s paradox in which an honest person says they are honest and a liar does too. On the outside you can’t tell the difference, but on the inside they are fundamentally opposite. It also reminds me very much of King Lear where the two daughters that say everything to win political favor and advantage turn out to be the most corrupt, whereas the daughter who is quietly loyal and true and doesn’t put on an act or have to prove herself to anyone, for refusing to partake in insincere flattery, is misunderstood as disrespectful but by the end is recognized as the King’s true ally.

It’s sort of like a paradox that the more concerned people are with fairness, the more open-minded, questioning, self-searching, morally self-scrutinizing they are, the less ease they have in outrightly condemning other people; whereas people who are one-sided, make overconfident misjudgments, assume the worst about other people, presume their own incontestable more supremacy, are precisely the ones who vent so much against others - the moral seems less moral, the immoral seems more, on the surface.

Is there a cool idiom for that?

Comment: Could you give a specific example? It's hard to understand specifically what you're referring to. My first inclination was "the pot calling the kettle black." There's also the neologism "whataboutism".

Comment: Sounds like bullying behaviour...

Answer (score 2):

The obvious choice, if you want to accuse someone of attacking you when they themselves are more guilty, is:

> Those who live in glass houses should not throw stones. ([See Cambridge.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/people-who-live-in-glass-houses-shouldn-t-throw-stones))

There's also the oft-quoted Bible verse:

> Why do you look at the speck of sawdust in your brother’s eye and pay no attention to the plank in your own eye? (Matthew 7:3, NIV)

The term **"whataboutism"** may also describe this phenomenon. [MW defines it as:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whataboutism)

> **whataboutism:** the act or practice of responding to an accusation of wrongdoing by claiming that an offense committed by another is similar or worse

There's also a relevant quote from Confucius:

> The Master said, "When we see men of worth, we should think of equaling them; when we see men of a contrary character, we should turn inwards and examine ourselves." (*Analects* IV, [see this page from USC](https://china.usc.edu/confucius-analects-4))

And one more related quote from the Bible:

> Judge not, that ye be not judged. (Matthew 7:1, KJV)

Answer (score 2):

One riposte to such people is:

*It takes one to know one*

> [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/it-takes-one-to-know-one)
> *it takes one to know one*
> Definition
> used for saying that someone must have a bad quality themselves if they can recognize it in other people
> ‘He’s a complete idiot!’ ‘Well, it takes one to know one!’

The saying implies that those who have a fault are so familiar with it that they wrongly imagine others have it too. In accusing others of the fault they reveal that they themselves have it to a greater extent.